# Identity Server 4 Multi-tenancy logout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm currently developing an identity server. It is multi-tenant with multiple user repositories.

I am able to pass (using Services.OpenIDConnect.Options) my tenant details from my MVC to the IDS in order to select the appropriate user repository on login

```
options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
{                        
    context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("Tenant", "TenantDetail");
    return Task.CompletedTask;
};
```

I am attempting to obtain this same information for logout, however the initial call to logout has some back end process that calls CustomProfileService.IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context).

I am unable to obtain the tenant information from the IsActiveContext, nor am i able to read any kind of query string (as i was using for login).

Any suggestions, or even alternative methods that might be more correct than what I'm attempting, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The context contains `Subject`, which is a `ClaimsPrincipal`; you should be able to add a tenant ID claim (if you don’t already have one) and get it that way?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg that statement means nothing to me. I don't understand what that is.

Comment: This is called on signout: `options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = context => { context.ProtocolMessage.AcrValues = "tenant:TenantName" }`. And in IdentityServer logout: `var context = await _interaction.GetLogoutContextAsync(logoutId);`

Comment: @RuardvanElburg my issue happens prior to the logout method in the IDS, its when it attempts to validate the user prior to doing anything in the IsActiveAsync call looking at IsActiveContext

Comment: Can you show the code from `IsActiveAsync` that you have so far? Because I wonder how you solved this for signin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnRedirectToIdentityProvider` will not be hit on signout. You'll need to pass the tenant information in the `OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut` event in your client instead.

Here's a snippet, that's far from complete:

```
services
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
        {
            OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = context =>
            {
                context.ProtocolMessage.AcrValues = "tenant:TenantDetail";
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            },
        }
    }
```

In IdentityServer you'll need to lookup the acr_values in the query parameters from the request. Inject IHttpContextAccessor in order to access the context:

```
public class ProfileService : IProfileService
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public ProfileService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public async Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {
        // Please note that this method is called on many occasions. Check context.Caller
        // This means that you'll have to make sure that the acr_valus are present on all
        // ocassions, hence the question in my comment.

        var request = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request;
        if (request.Method == HttpMethods.Get)
        {
            // acr_values should be present on all ocassions.
            var values = (string)request.Query["acr_values"];

            // This is just a sample, you'll need to parse the values.
            var tenant = values.Split(':')[1];
        }

        // Your code where you link the repository ...

        var sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
        var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(sub);
        context.IsActive = user != null;
    }
}
```

Please let me know if this solves the issue for you.

Comment: This works, and slight retooling made it work in all the cases I needed it. Thank you!